# extract dates from a string in excel and copied over to a new row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How can I extract dates from String in Microsoft excel cell? I have the following information on Cell A

In Cell A2 I have: `360485`
In Cell B2 I have (Note: Its wrap text in a single cell):

> ```
>   10/7 - comment 1
>   5/3/16 - comment 2
>   3/21/16 comment 3
>   1/26/16 - comment 4"
> ```

I want to to get something like this

> ```
> Col A    Col B      Col C
> 360485  10/7/16   - comment 1
> 360485  5/3/16    - comment 2
> 360485  3/21/16     comment 3
> 360485  1/26/16   - comment 4"
> ```

@JNevill,

Data in Col A: `600537L`
Data in Col B

```
6/21/17 - text comment 1 
951396-LH/RH-951554
10/27 - text comment 2
normal text
2/5/16 - text comment 3"
```

Result

```
 Col A    Col B                      Col C
600537L 6/21/2017             - text comment 1
600537L 951396-LH/RH-951554 
600537L 27-Oct               - text comment 2
600537L normal               text
600537L 2/5/2016             - text comment 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following will get you in the ballpark:

```
Sub test()
    'get that ugly b2 value into an array split by line
    Dim b2Array As Variant
    b2Array = Split(Sheet1.Range("B2"), Chr(10))

    'grab the value in a2
    Dim a2Value As String
    a2Value = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value

    'loop through the array (each line in B2 and output. Making use of more `split` here to grab values
    Dim writeRow As Integer: writeRow = 1
    For Each element In b2Array
        Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 1).Value = a2Value
        Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 2).Value = Trim(Split(Trim(element), " ")(0))
        Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 3).Value = Trim(Replace(element, Split(Trim(element), " ")(0), ""))
        writeRow = writeRow + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

That's assuming this is on Sheet1 and you are wanting to output to Sheet2.

Comment: I tried your solution, attached the result at the bottom of my question above. I also have more than 300 number of rows, I think your solution works for one row is there any way to update the range?

Comment: I think this is still the right way to go though. I see the results, but you haven't explained what's wrong with them. They look fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2010 or later, you can do this using Power Query (aka Get&Transform), and then refresh the query if you add more rows.

- Split Column 2 by `linefeed character` into **Rows**
- Trim Column 2 to remove leading and trailing spaces
- Split by `space` into columns, but only the left-most space

Here is the M-Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns
            (Source, {{"Column2", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.Csv), 
            let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column2"),

    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column2", type text}}),

    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Trim", each Text.Trim([Column2])),

    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Column2"}),

    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", 
            "Trim", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Trim.1", "Trim.2"})
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1"
```

### Original data

[image]

### Results

[image]